# find the position of an element in a list in bash

Tags: bash

I am using bash. I need to find the position of a given element in a list.

I have searched for solutions but they all only check if an element exists in a list instead of finding the index.

```
#!/bin/bash

LIST=(A B C D)

# index_of_A = LIST.index('A') # which should return 0

echo ${LIST[${index_of_A}]} # prints 'A'
```

Or is it impossible to do this through bash?

---

EDIT: remove dash

Comment: Can you try this 'arr =($LIST)  echo ${arr[1]}'

Comment: This question doesn't apply to `dash`, since you are using an array.

Comment: @AnantKolvankar I tried your code but I don't get it :\

Comment: Did it give any error??

Comment: @AnantKolvankar No. ${arr[1]} returns nothing since only ${arr[0]} has value.

Comment: ${arr[0]} has value you mean complete value of LIST A B C D

Comment: @AnantKolvankar Right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you insist on a clever / inefficient / awkward way:

```bash
#! /bin/bash

indexof()
{
    local word
    local item
    local idx

    word=$1
    shift
    item=$(printf '%s\n' "$@" | fgrep -nx "$word")
    let idx=${item%%:*}-1
    echo $idx
}

list=(A B C D)
indexof C "${list[@]}"    # 2
indexof Z "${list[@]}"    # -1
```

This works as long as the elements of your list don't contain newlines.

Comment: Yours is a really interesting solution! Though it seems that to find the index I must write multiple lines instead of calling simple built-in commands, which is disappointing.

Comment: @TingYiShih Yeah, hence "inefficient" and "awkward".

Comment: Also, shouldn't you quote your variables/command-substitutions?

Comment: Sorry my previous comment was incorrect: is there any advantage to using `printf '%s\n' "$@" | CMD 'pattern'` over `CMD 'pattern' <<<"$@"`?

Answer (score 4):

First, let's define the list:

```
list=(A B C D)
```

Next, let's define a function to find the index of elements:

```
indexof() { i=0; while [ "$i" -lt "${#list[@]}" ] && [ "${list[$i]}" != "$1" ]; do ((i++)); done; echo $i; }
```

Now, it is easy to find the index of elements of array `list`:

```
$ indexof "A"
0
$ indexof "C"
2
```

If we ask for the index of an element that is not in `list`, we get one more than the largest index in the array:

```
$ indexof "E"
4
```

#### Alternative

Depending on your programming background, you might prefer that the index of an unknown element be returned as `-1`.  In that case:

```
indexof() { i=-1; for ((j=0;j<${#list[@]};j++)); do [ "${list[$j]}" = "$1" ] && { i=$j; break; } done; echo $i; }
```

For example:

```
$ indexof "A"
0
$ indexof "B"
1
$ indexof "E"
-1
```

Comment: I'm expecting alternatives other than iterating over the list on my own.... But still appreciate your answer. I'll wait for days until there is really no other way to do it, and I'll accept your answer then :)

Comment: @TingYiShih I doubt there is a way to do this without iterating over the list in a function or in an external system command.  I also don't understand the issue with said methodology: if you write a function to accomplish this task for you, then you can just call it like a simple command: you write a function that allows you to perform a complex task with a simple command.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that the array values are unique (or else one would need to define more precisely what an “index” means (first one / last one / any / all matching)), the best option might be to pre-index the array into a reverse mapping (== an integer-valued associative array). Advantages:

- Subsequent use of the reverse mapping avoids repeated linear traversals of the array. The complexity of an index lookup is sub-linear (e.g. constant or logarithmic, depending on underlying implementation).
- The solution uses zero external processes (i.e. only Bash itself).

```
create_reverse() {
  declare -gAi "$2"
  local -nr array="$1"
  local -n mapping="$2"
  local -i index
  mapping=()
  for index in "${!array[@]}"; do
    mapping["${array[index]}"]="$((index))"
  done
}

index_of() {
  local -r value="$1"
  local -nr reverse="$2"
  echo "$((reverse["$value"]))"
}

list=(zero one two three four five)

create_reverse list reverse_mapping_of_list

index_of zero reverse_mapping_of_list   # 0
index_of three reverse_mapping_of_list  # 3
index_of five reverse_mapping_of_list   # 5
```